# How to prevent citation call-outs in natbib from being translated to German?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, languages

When I compile my document with pdflatex with `natbib` and either the `plainnat` or the `dinat` style on my computer, the author list is translated to German. E.g., I get "und" between authors instead of "and" and instead of "et al" I get "u. a.".

I am very puzzled, because I don't know why.

- In my bibliography file all references are in English and I also write "and" between each author. So the original is in English and there obviously happens an unwanted translation somewhere.
- When I upload the very same document (i.e. all .tex files and also the .cls file, exactly as they are on my computer) to Overleaf, everything is fine and the compiled document has all references in English.

I use `TexStudio` to write and I also compile from `TexStudio`. Could it be because of `TexStudio`? What could I change to make sure that nothing is translated?

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test document  which allows users to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd be puzzled by the fact that the `dinat` bibliography style generates citation call-outs with German-language particles, such as "und" and "u.a.", instead of "and" and "et al". After all, that's exactly what the `dinat` bibliography style is programmed to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{jones-smith:3001,
  author = "Anna Jones and Carla Smith",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{jones-miller-smith:3002,
  author = "Anna Jones and Brenda Miller and Carla Smith",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{jones-smith:3001}, \citep{jones-miller-smith:3002}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

In contrast, I am *unable* to reproduce this issue when using the `plainnat` bibliography style. I.e., using the same test document as above but employing `plainnat` instead of `dinat`, I get this outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that dinat is German, because of norm by the German institute of norming. I also couldn't reproduce a plainnat translation in German. It works now for me too! Thank you again!